# Got ImportError: No module named _util while running scrapy crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, pyopenssl

I am running a scrapy spider in the following virtual environment:

```
Python 2.7.10

Package                 Version    
----------------------- -----------
:
:      
pyOpenSSL               18.0.0     
:
:
```

It seems to have the latest version of pyOpenSSL. However, when I run:

```
scrapy crawl launch_dates
```

I get the following error:

```
2018-12-13 12:29:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: 
test_webcrawler)
2018-12-13 12:29:27 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, 
libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 
 18.9.0, Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 19:45:58) - [GCC 4.2.1 
Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)], pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 
(LibreSSL 2.2.7), cryptography 2.4.2, Platform Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64- 
i386-64bit
2018-12-13 12:29:27 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'test_webcrawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['test_webcrawler.spiders'], 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 
'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 
'BOT_NAME': 'test_webcrawler', 'LOG_STDOUT': True, 'USER_AGENT': 
'circles_bot', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
:
:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site- 
packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 15, in <module>   
   from OpenSSL._util import lib as pyOpenSSLlib
ImportError: No module named _util
```

Has anyone faced the same issue? I am seeking for any hint to solve it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running Scrapy but it error: No module named \_util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324329/running-scrapy-but-it-error-no-module-named-util)

Comment: No, this question has been resolved by upgrading pyOpenSSL. Unfortunately, my version of pyOpenSSL is already the latest one...

Comment: @V.Foy I would recommend using a Virtual Environment, as it looks like you are installing everything directly in your system.

Comment: @eLRuLL I am already using a virtual environment. pyOpenSSL looks to up-to-date in the ladder... :(

Comment: Have you solved the issue?