# can't run scrapy in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, virtual-machine

I've set up using Vagrant & VirtualBox, I have installed scrapy correctly and when I run

```
/program$ scrapy -v
Scrapy 1.6.0 - no active project
```

however when I run `scrapy shell https://www.google.com` I get the following error

```
from OpenSSL._util import lib as pyOpenSSLlib
ImportError: No module named _util
```

I tried `sudo pip install pyopenssl --user --upgrade` from the following same question [running Scrapy but it error: No module named _util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324329/running-scrapy-but-it-error-no-module-named-util)
but it did not fix . I use python 2.7

Comment: Please clarify: do you use the `virtualenv` package (as per the queation title)? Or were you referring to the fact that you use a virtual machine?

Comment: @malberts it's virtualenv in virtual machine

Comment: Run `pip freeze` and attach that list here.

Answer (score 0):

I guess pyopenssl is not the latest version. Upgrade it and retry.

general format to upgrade package using pip is :

`sudo pip install [package_name] --upgrade`

hence use :

`sudo pip install pyopenssl --upgrade`

(make sure the virtualenv you are using is active)

Comment: Thank you but i tried this solution but it didn'work so i removed it and reinstalled it but still same problem

Comment: could you run pip freeze and attach that list here so that everyone can see the list?