# getting same error after upgrading pyopenssl ImportError: No module named _util

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, environment-variables, libssl

i have upgraded pyopenssl but still getting the same error.

```
python 2.7
Name: pyOpenSSL
Version: 0.13
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

from OpenSSL._util import lib as pyOpenSSLlib
ImportError: No module named _util
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running Scrapy but it error: No module named \_util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324329/running-scrapy-but-it-error-no-module-named-util)

Comment: i have tried all the possible way from above link but it's not working.